# Dovecot isn't working after upgrading MariaDB

Tags: dovecot, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I've just updated my database engine to MariaDB (5.5.40-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)).
  Everything else (Apache2 :80, :443, phpMyAdmin, Webmin, etc.) but Dovecot is working.

I'm not quite sure which package needs to be installed to replace the /usr/lib/dovecot shared libraries that enable Dovecot to talk to MariaDB.  Mysql used to use libdriver_mysql.so, and a couple others.

Anyone able to advise?

**Edit**
I removed MySQL using

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common  
apt-get autoremove  
apt-get autoclean
```

These commands also removed PHPMYADMIN and MYSQLI.  So when I installed MariaDB, I included the following packages:

```
apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client libmariadbclient-dev libmariadbd-dev phpmyadmin
```

You might not require the `dev` packages, but I installed them anyway.
To get phpMyAdmin working again on SSL only, I had to reconfigure *etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf* to include the http=>https rewrite.

Comment: mariadb is completely compatible with mysql library. Could you show the maillog?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the packages below:

```
apt-get install dovecot-mysql  
apt-get install libclass-dbi-mysql-perl
```

I also reinstalled

```
apt-get install php-auth
apt-get install php-pear
apt-get install postfix-mysql
```

You might find that these last three are already installed by *libclass-dbi-mysql-perl* but on my test server I had to manually install them.

Everything is now working fine.  :)